# Method return in Kotlin & Java

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-architecture-components

I'm learning Kotlin. I have weird a situation.

I have method in java:

```
@Override
public NavDestination navigate(@NonNull Destination destination,
                               @Nullable Bundle args,
                               @Nullable NavOptions navOptions,
                               @Nullable Extras navigatorExtras) {

    ....
    return navDestination ;
}
```

and code in Kotlin

```
override fun navigate(destination: Destination, 
                      args: Bundle?, 
                      navOptions: NavOptions?, 
                      navigatorExtras: Extras?) {
       ....
    }
```

My question is: Why does the method in Kotlin not return anything? 
When we look for the docs 
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/Navigator.html#navigate(D,%20android.os.Bundle,%20androidx.navigation.NavOptions,%20androidx.navigation.Navigator.Extras)

You can see that the method returns something.

Thanks for reply.

Comment: `My question is: Why does the method in Kotlin not return anything` because there's no `return` in you kotlin code?

Comment: Does the kotlin code compile? Have you used auto-code-conversion? Maybe it's just a bug in the code converter?

Comment: Your function should be: `override fun navigate(destination: Destination, 
                      args: Bundle?, 
                      navOptions: NavOptions?, 
                      navigatorExtras: Extras?): NavDestination` and of course you need a return statement inside the function's block.

Comment: Simply add a return statement inside the method.

Comment: Method works. Full code:
https://github.com/STAR-ZERO/navigation-dialog-sample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/navigationdialog/DialogNavigator.kt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link to the documentation you mention links to release `1.0.0` of the library. But you use version `1.0.0-alpha06`. There was a change in the method signature from `alpha06`

```
public abstract void navigate(@NonNull D destination, @Nullable Bundle args, @Nullable NavOptions navOptions, @Nullable Extras navigatorExtras);
```

to `1.0.0` stable:

```
public abstract NavDestination navigate(@NonNull D destination, @Nullable Bundle args, @Nullable NavOptions navOptions, @Nullable Extras navigatorExtras);
```

If you change in your build.gradle the following dependencies

```
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:1.0.0"
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:1.0.0"
```

you'll get a compiler error due to the missing return statement.